# Splitting data in SAS by categorical column

Tags: split, automation, sas, categorical-data

I have a categorical column in my dataset which has around 20 or more categories. Now I want to create seperate dataset for all these categories.

Example: if the category is A, B, C, .... then I need table A containing A data, table B containing B data etc.

Comment: Without using PROC SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classic use of the SAS Hash Object

```
data have;
input category $ value;
datalines;
A 1 
A 2 
A 3 
B 4 
B 5 
B 6 
C 7 
C 8 
C 9 
;

data want;
   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      dcl hash h(dataset : 'have(obs = 0)', multidata : 'Y');
      h.definekey(all : 'Y');
      h.definedone();
   end;

   do until (last.category);
      set have;
      by category;
      h.add();
   end;

   h.output(dataset : catx('_', 'table', category));
   h.clear();
run;
```